# Application crash due to validation - 'This property cannot be set to a null value'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, null

I have created the following view for users to create new items. Ive tried to create a bit of validation so if the user leaves a field blank, then it produces a validation message. However, if the user does leave a field blank, my application crashes on the following line: `_headline = structuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false)` in the Model.Designer.cs file. because:

> This property cannot be set to a null value.

Part of my Model.Designer.cs file:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String headline
    {
        get
        {
            return _headline;
        }
        set
        {
            OnheadlineChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("headline");
      _headline = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("headline");
            OnheadlineChanged();
        }
    }
```

The section of code this applies to is as follows in my Create View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>

    <legend>News Details</legend>

    <br />
        Posted Date:
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.posted)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.posted)
            </div>

    <br />

        Headline Title:
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.headline)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.headline)
            </div>

    <br />
```

The following is my AccountModels.cs file where i entered the validation for the View:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(NewsValidation))]

public partial class News
{
}

public class NewsValidation
{

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Posted date is required")]
    public DateTime posted { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Headline is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Headline")]
    public string headline { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Story body is required")]
   public string story { get; set; }
}
```

I was told it was because my database allowed Null values however since then i have created a new database which no longer allows Nulls. My application still crashes and dont know where to start. Here's the odd thing, when it crashes, i click play for it to continue, and the validation appears. So it looks like the validation works but for some reason by application crashes beforehand.

Can anyone offer any support?

Comment: I don't know much about MVC but... shouldn't the `IsNullable=false` part be causing the issue?

Comment: I'll try that however the Model.Designer.cs file is generated automatically. Thank you for looking :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the setter of the `headline` property on your domain model is attempting to perform the update. This setter is invoked by the default model binder when it attempts to bind the action argument from the request. And if the user leaves the headlines field blank you will get this exception.

I would very strongly recommend you using view models and never passing your domain models to the view. So define a simple NewsViewModel:

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Headline { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action pass it to the view:

```
public class HeadlinesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new NewsViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(NewsViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // there were validation errors. For example the user
            // left the headline field blank => redisplay the view
            return View(model);
        }

        // at this stage we know that validation passed => we can 
        // process our domain model.
        var news = new News();
        news.posted = model.Posted;
        news.headline = model.Headline;

        return RedirectToAction("success");
    }
}
```

and obviously the view will be now strongly typed to your view model:

```
@model NewsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>News Details</legend>

        <br />
        Posted Date:
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Posted)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Posted)
        </div>

        <br />

        Headline Title:
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Headline)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Headline)
        </div>

        <br />

        <button type="submit">OK</submit>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: my current 'create' view looks a different to yours, would the above still apply?  
   [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
   public ActionResult Create(News news)
   {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     var latestStory = _db.News.OrderByDescending(n =>       n.storyId).FirstOrDefault();
     var nextStoryId = latestStory.storyId + 1;
     news.storyId = nextStoryId;
     _db.News.AddObject(news);
     _db.SaveChanges();
     TempData["StoryCreated"] = "New story was created successfully";
     return RedirectToAction("UniversityHomepage");
    }
    return View(news);
   }

Comment: @user1091114, no, don't use News as argument of your controller action. That's the problem. The default model binder invokes the setter. And the setter crash the way you implemented it (actually not you but in the autogenerated file). You should define a NewsViewModel as I explained in my answer and use this view model.

Comment: When i run my application i receive the following in my IE window: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'File.Models.NewsViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'File.Models.News'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.'  
Is that because I'm doing: Return View(model); instead of just Return View()?

Comment: @user1091114, aren't you following my answer? Did you notice the `@model NewsViewModel` line in the beginning of my view? This is what indicates that your view is now strongly typed to the `NewsViewModel` and no longer using the `News` domain model.

Comment: Sorry i didnt put in @model NewsViewModel in my view. I get he following error when loading the create page:  
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NewsViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Line 29:public class _Page_Views_Home_Create_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<NewsViewModel> {

Answer (score 0):

If the application crashes but you can click play and it happily carries on and performs the validation, is your debugging set to show all thrown exceptions rather than just user-unhandled ones? Perhaps `StructuralObject.SetValidValue()` is using an exception for flow control.

1. Go to Debug > Exceptions
2. If you don't have a 'User-unhandled' column, Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General and check Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)
3. In Debug > Exceptions, uncheck 'Thrown' and check 'User-unhandled' under **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**

Just a hunch - does it make any difference?

Comment: Hi Steve,
I think this is a problem with my code since its just not picking the validation up before processing. Ive check my settings:  User Exceptions: C++ Exceptions, Common Language Runtime Exceptions, Managed Debugging Assistants, Native Run-Time Checks and Win32 Exceptions all have ticks under 'User-unhandled'. Non are ticked for 'Thrown'. 'Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)' is also ticked.
Thank you for replying :-)